# What's keeping this simple CNN from classifying whether an image contains a cat or not?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

Instead of "cats vs dogs", I'm trying "cats vs. everything else" on a brand new network (no transfer learning) using a large number of random internet images I've sorted into "cat" or "no cat" categories.

Unfortunately, my network won't seem to train itself past random for this task.

My networks have been basic multi-layer CNNs, with a single large dense layer and then one single sigmoid neuron at the end to output 0 or 1 to signify "yes cat" or "no cat". My "cat" images consist of many cropped images of various breeds of cat in many poses and angles, in differing environments and backgrounds. I've tried various forms of data augmentation and image weighting and data/validation shuffling but still can't get a useful network out of it.

What am I missing? Is there something wrong with my architecture or approach? I'm a machine learning newbie, and using Keras over Tensorflow.

My network architecture is as follows:

```
Input 320x320 RGB image into network, then:

1a) Conv layer, 32 filters, 3x3
1b) Relu and max pooling 2x2.

2a) Conv layer, 32 filters, 3x3
2b) Relu and max pooling 2x2

3a) Conv layer, 64 filters, 3x3
3b) Relu and max pooling 2x2

4) Flatten

5a) Dense 64 neurons
5b) Relu
5c) Dropout 0.5
5d) Final dense 1 neuron, sigmoid activation. (0 = cat in image, 1 = no cat in image)
```

I'm using binary cross-entropy, and image rotation/shift/flip/etc. for data augmentation. My dataset is highly imbalanced with 1 cat picture for every 5 non-cat pictures. I've reserved 25% of my dataset is reserved for validation, with the same 1:5 imbalance. I have weighted the fit generator to give cat images a 5x higher weighting as a result.

Is there a problem with the architecture, initialization, etc. or am I simply severely underestimating the time it takes to train a CNN from scratch on modern hardware?

Comment: (Not sure but) The models I see for real world image classification are usually bigger than that. So the first suggestion is: add two convs before each maxpooling (instead of just one conv). Try more groups before flatten. 4 or 5 groups of (2xConv + MaxPooling) instead of just 3.

Comment: Do you normalize input images?  What is the of the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

The "cats vs dogs" example often uses VGG16 as in the [fast.ai](http://course.fast.ai/) course.

Its 16-layer network was used by the VGG team in the [ILSVRC-2014 ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2014/) competition.
See [one implementation in Keras](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3).

You could probably download the weights, then apply that to your problem after downscaling your images to (3 channels x 224x224 pixels).

Comment: Using VGG or Inception would be faster, but I'm trying to make this one work from scratch, and it only has to discriminate between "image contains any common fruit" and "image contains no fruit". I'm not sure where my network is going wrong, and I'm wondering if I've made it too complex, or maybe not complex enough? Or if I'm missing a fundamental piece of the puzzle for this project I came up with. I haven't seen many resources for training a network on whether an object is present or not. It's always cats vs. dogs, or apples vs. oranges. Not "any kind of common fruit" vs "everything else".

Comment: Why don't you try the "fine-tuning" approach first, as mentioned in this answer, and see if your model performs any better than your "from scratch" model. If it does, then you could look at the architecture from VGG16 and get an idea of how to possibly improve your original model. Resources for fine-tuning if you're not familiar: https://youtu.be/jp5LZVeJkow and https://youtu.be/xH7VHHISWxU

Comment: Thanks, @blackHoleDetector. After purposefully avoiding it to try to make it work on my own, I finally decided to try bootstrapping on top of the VGG16 architecture, and it worked amazingly well. I don't think I'll be trying to build my own visual CNNs from scratch for quite a while, if ever. Now that I've attempted it, I can see how difficult and intensive the task is. Thanks a lot for your advice, it pushed me to finally try using an existing architecture instead of from scratch.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.